# deck.gl + tripslayer without react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deck.gl

How can I enable animation of TripsLayer without react? TripsLayer example uses React and I really don't know, how to convert it to pure js. Please look at "animate" function in the code below. I tried to update state of layer but it doesn't work (there is no animation of TripsLayer). I don't know, where should I assign "time" variable.

Demo of TripsLayer: https://deck.gl/#/examples/custom-layers/trip-routes

React version my code: https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/blob/master/examples/website/trips/app.js

Docs for TripsLayer: https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/tree/master/modules/experimental-layers/src/trips-layer

My code:

```
import {MapboxLayer} from '@deck.gl/mapbox';
import {TripsLayer} from '@deck.gl/experimental-layers';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

class App
{
  constructor()
  {
    this.stateInfo = { time: 600 };
  }

  get state()
  {
    return this.stateInfo;
  }

  animate() {
    var loopLength = 18000; // unit corresponds to the timestamp in source data
    var animationSpeed = 30; // unit time per second

    const timestamp = Date.now() / 1000;
    const loopTime = loopLength / animationSpeed;

    var time = Math.round(((timestamp % loopTime) / loopTime) * loopLength);

    // HOW SHOULD I USE time VARIABLE???

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this)); 
  }
}

var obido = new App();

var tripsLayerObido = new TripsLayer({
  id: 'trips',
  data: 'trips/tripsKR.json',
  getPath: d => d.segments,
  getColor: d => (d.vendor === 0 ? [253, 128, 93] : [23, 184, 190]),
  opacity: 0.6,
  strokeWidth: 30,
  trailLength: 180,
  currentTime: obido.state.time
});

const LIGHT_SETTINGS = {
  lightsPosition: [-74.05, 40.7, 8000, -73.5, 41, 5000],
  ambientRatio: 0.05,
  diffuseRatio: 0.6,
  specularRatio: 0.8,
  lightsStrength: [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  numberOfLights: 2
};

export const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
  longitude: 19.93,
  latitude: 50.03,
  zoom: 12.8,
  maxZoom: 19,
  pitch: 60,
  bearing: 0
};


mapboxgl.accessToken = "XXX";
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'app',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/elninopl/cjnlge6rl094w2so70l1cf8y5',
  center: [INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.longitude, INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.latitude],
  zoom: INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.zoom,
  pitch: INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.pitch,
  layers: [tripsLayerObido]
});

map.on('load', () => {
  obido.animate(0);
});
```

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to explain exactly what happens ('it doesn't work' isn't helpful). I would also have another look at the tags (suggest you add javascript, for a start). Finally, please clarify why you don't want to use react. Thanks.

Comment: I would also suggest that you create an example that someone can come along and easily pick up.

I would suggest that your problem is that you are never telling anything to re-render. The `this.setState` in React triggers a render, which you aren't doing here.

You want something along the lines of `deck.setProps`, but you're combining mapbox custom layers with Deck GL and I'm not sure how to do it there.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `setProps`, which makes my trips layer updates:

```
this.tripsLayer.setProps({ currentTime: this.currentTime });
```

Answer (score 0):

yes,it works.

```
function animate(timestamp) {
  var timestamp = Date.now() / 1000;
  var loopTime = loopLength / animationSpeed;
  curtime= ((timestamp % loopTime) / loopTime) * loopLength;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  tripLayer.setProps({ currentTime: curtime });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late here, but [here](https://codepen.io/AdriSolid/pen/abByNvZ) there is an example of using deck.gl `TripsLayer` with the **Scripting API** (without React).

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/deck.gl@^8.4.0/dist.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@deck.gl/carto@^8.4.0/dist.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://libs.cartocdn.com/mapbox-gl/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://libs.cartocdn.com/mapbox-gl/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="map" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh"></div>

const ambientLight = new deck.AmbientLight({
  color: [255, 255, 255],
  intensity: 1.0
});

const pointLight = new deck.PointLight({
  color: [255, 255, 255],
  intensity: 2.0,
  position: [-74.05, 40.7, 8000]
});

const lightingEffect = new deck.LightingEffect({ ambientLight, pointLight });

const material = {
  ambient: 0.1,
  diffuse: 0.6,
  shininess: 32,
  specularColor: [60, 64, 70]
};

const theme = {
  buildingColor: [74, 80, 87],
  trailColor0: [253, 128, 93],
  trailColor1: [23, 184, 190],
  material,
  effects: [lightingEffect]
};

const LOOP_LENGTH = 1800;
const ANIMATION_SPEED = 0.4;

async function initialize() {
  deck.carto.setDefaultCredentials({
    username: 'public',
    apiKey: 'default_public',
  });

  // Fetch Data from CARTO
  // Notice that you can use any Deck.gl layer with CARTO datasets getting GeoJSON data from CARTO's API. This method is recommended for complex layers with datasets below 50Mb
  const tripsUrl = 'https://public.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT the_geom, vendor, timestamps FROM sf_trips_v7&format=geojson';
  const geojsonTripsData = await fetch(tripsUrl).then(response => response.json());
  // TripsLayer needs data in the following format
  const layerData = geojsonTripsData.features.map(f => ({
    vendor: f.properties.vendor,
    timestamps: f.properties.timestamps,
    path: f.geometry.coordinates[0]
  }));

  const staticLayers = [
    // This is only needed when using shadow effects
    new deck.PolygonLayer({
      id: 'ground-layer',
      data: [[[-74.0, 40.7], [-74.02, 40.7], [-74.02, 40.72], [-74.0, 40.72]]],
      getPolygon: f => f,
      stroked: false,
       getFillColor: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    }),
    new deck.carto.CartoSQLLayer({
      id: 'buildings-layer',
      data: 'SELECT the_geom_webmercator, height FROM sf_buildings',
      extruded: true,
      wireframe: true,
      opacity: 0.5,
      getElevation: f => f.properties.height,
      getFillColor: [74, 80, 87],
      material: theme.material
    })
  ];

  // Create Deck.GL map
  const deckgl = new deck.DeckGL({
    container: 'map',
    mapStyle: 'https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/gl/dark-matter-nolabels-gl-style/style.json',
    initialViewState: {
      longitude: -74,
      latitude: 40.73,
      zoom: 12,
      pitch: 45,
      bearing: 0
    },
    controller: true,
    layers: staticLayers,
    effects: theme.effects
  });

  let time = 0;

  function animate() {
    time = (time + ANIMATION_SPEED) % LOOP_LENGTH;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

  setInterval(() => {
    deckgl.setProps({
      layers: [
        ...staticLayers,
        new deck.TripsLayer({
          id: 'trips-layer',
          data: layerData,
          getPath: d => d.path,
          getTimestamps: d => d.timestamps,
          getColor: d => (d.vendor === 0 ? theme.trailColor0 : theme.trailColor1),
          opacity: 0.3,
          widthMinPixels: 2,
          rounded: true,
          trailLength: 180,
          currentTime: time,
          shadowEnabled: false
        })
      ]
    });
  }, 50);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 }

 initialize();
```